# getElementsByTagName not saving (only works in chrome)

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

This code works in Chrome, but fails in Firefox, IE, and Safari. The specific break is when the if statement comes up. I've debugged through it, and when it hits a true statement it ignores it and doesn't step into the If statement.

```
function injectId()
{
    //take over their old stuff
    var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0, len = imgElements.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (imgElements[i].src == "http://imageurl/imagename.png") {
            imgElements[i].id = tabs[0];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Sidenotes:
I struggled for awhile using non-chrome dev tools because they remap the names.  For example, if you break on the start of the for-loop and try to add "imgElements" to watch, it will throw you an "undefined reference" error.  Instead I had to find the mapped variable (t in this case) and I also had to find the mapped index variable (e) to find the source.

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: are you using relative paths for the images

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dpchq2h7/

My guess is the issue is `tabs[0]`, which, depending on what tabs is could cause browser specific issues.